# WP_Query wooCommerce category

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic

What is the favored way for searching for a certain category in wooCommerce? Or maybe only checking if it is existent already?

My approach for this was:

```
                $searchCat = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_title' => $cat,
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        'terms' => 'group'
                    )
                ));
```

where $cat represens the textual name of the category.

Also, how would you go about adding a category? I think I worked out the post parameters wrong, thus my adding function won't do any better.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks strange that you use $cat as post title. It is more likely to be part of the tax query part. In addition you have two questions in one, try to edit this one to leave only one of them and start a new one for the other. hmmm, woocomerce questions are ignored by many people here for several reasons so it is better if you can ask your question without mentioning it ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code to check whether a category with a name exist of not

```
$search_category_name="T-shirts";
//This gets top layer terms only.  This is done by setting parent to 0.  
    $parent_terms = get_terms('product_cat', array('orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));

    foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
        //check whether the category_name exists
        if ($search_category_name == $pterm->name) {
            return true;
        }           
    }
```

And for creating a new one you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690047/how-to-programatically-set-the-category-for-a-new-woocommerce-product-creation) link